# Get X-Y coordinates for GridViewCell on GUI

Tags: c#, telerik, silverlight-5.0, radgridview

I have an activity to provide **Intellesence** functionality to the user for **RadRichTextBox** placed inside **RadGridView**. I have implemented the functionality for intellesence by using **RadListBox**.

But i am facing problem while ***displying*** the RadListBox at certain **location** where user is typing.

To resolve the problem, a need to calculate the **X-Y coordinates of GridViewCell** in which my RadRichTextBox is placed.

Once i will get the coordinates for GridViewCell than that can be used to calculate the actual position where user is typing.

SO what i finally want the GridViewCell X-Y coordinates relative to my current view on GUI.

This functionality will be implemented in a **Silverlight** application using **Telerik** controls.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

```
GeneralTransform globalTransform = gridViewParent.CurrentCell.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual);
Point transformedPoint = globalTransform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```